# Cucumber Runner class not working

Tags: cucumber

Hi i have create d a feature file and for that also created  a step definition class file but when i am trying to run feature from Cucumber runner class each time it tells:

> You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

I am using Junit for running that file .

My Cucumber Runner class as below:

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
    features={"Features"},
    glue={"src.stepdefinition"},
    monochrome=false
            )
```

Comment: why not put the path to you feature file there in stead of putting just"Feature".

Answer (score 0):

once you run your `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` annotated class you have to complete the scenario test classes by using the code snippet provided by cucumber.

For example if you have a scenario named `Eat Cucumber` like the following:

```
Scenario: Eat cucumber
  Given I have a cucumber
```

after the run of your cucumber test class you should be able to create the following class with the snippet provided by its output:

```
public class EatCucumberSteps {
    @Given("^I have a cucumber$")
    public void I_have_a_cucumber() throws Throwable {
        // your implementation code here...
        throw new PendingException();
    }
    // add all your other missing steps
}
```